# Maven Eclipse Pom Error. I was trying to edit my pom to change the java but now I am getting a builder error and I cannot update maven pom

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
Receiver class com.baselet.plugin.MavenProjectChangedListener does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void mavenProjectChanged(java.util.List, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)' of interface org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IMavenProjectChangedListener.

I tried changing the version of java I was using from 1.8 to 17 but that caused the above error that would not leave the screen . I then after searching for answers managed to change it back to 1.8 but now that error keeps popping up and gets stuck on the screen . Could someone advise how to resolve this error. p.s. I am relatively new to eclipse maven .
Also i saw advice for the guy with the uml error but I changed it back to 1.8 so I do not understand why the error is still occuring.